# how to find the latest document in mongo db using moongoose

Tags: reactjs, mongodb, mongoose

Iam trying to store a list of product ids in an array in database and retrieve the latest array.
this is my server side code

```
router.post("/scannedproducts",async(request,response)=>{
    console.log(request.body)
    const Scannedproducts = new scannedproducts({
        ids:request.body
    }) 
    Scannedproducts.save()
    console.log(Scannedproducts)
    const getLatestProduct =await  scannedproducts.find().sort({ createdAt: -1 }).limit(1) // 10 latest docs
    console.log(getLatestProduct)  
})
```

but it consolelogs an empty array of ids.
please help...

Answer (score 0):

The mistake in your code is you should have used `await` while calling the `save()` method

Solution should be  :

```
router.post("/scannedproducts",async(request,response)=>{
    const Scannedproducts = new scannedproducts({
        ids:req.body
    }) 
    await Scannedproducts.save()
    console.log(Scannedproducts)
    const getLatestProduct =await  scannedproducts.find().sort({ createdAt:-1 }).limit(1) // 10 latest docs
    console.log(getLatestProduct)  
})
```

it would fix your issue,
But anyways You should have provided the `scannedProducts` model in your question, and assigning the whole request body object to a property is a bad practice. you should take an ids array as user input and store it in server
i would suggest you to write your code as:

```
router.post("/scannedproducts",async(request,response)=>{
    const Scannedproducts = new scannedproducts({
        ids:req.body.ids
    }) 
    await Scannedproducts.save()
    console.log(Scannedproducts)
    const getLatestProduct =await  scannedproducts.find().sort({ createdAt:-1 }).limit(1) // 10 latest docs
    console.log(getLatestProduct)  
})
```

Thank you

Comment: still its not working

Comment: when I console log getLatestProudct it prints this {}